# import Status returning message instead of status

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops

This peace of code is returning import message instead of status so I have changed the code for match the word with progress. actually why it is not returning status anyone please let me know.
I am running this code in Azure ADO pipeline .

```
$importStatus1 = Get-AzSqlDatabaseImportExportStatus -OperationStatusLink $importRequest.OperationStatusLink
    write-host "Importing"
    while ($importStatus1.Status -Match "Progress")
    {
        Start-Sleep -s 10
        $importStatus1 = Get-AzSqlDatabaseImportExportStatus -OperationStatusLink $importRequest.OperationStatusLink
         write-host  -NoNewline "."
    }
```

Comment: Not get your latest information, is the answer helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Comment: I cannot reproduce above issue. The `.status` return the correct result. Were you running above script in azure powershell task? What was the Azure PowerShell Version? And what was the agent you used to run the script?

Answer (score 0):

> This peace of code is returning import message instead of status so I
> have changed the code for match the word with progress.

For this issue, from the official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.sql/get-azsqldatabaseimportexportstatus?view=azps-5.2.0#description) description, we can know:

> The `Get-AzSqlDatabaseImportExportStatus` cmdlet gets **details** of a
> bacpac file import from a storage account to an Azure SQL Database or
> an export of an Azure SQL Database as a bacpac file to a storage
> account. This cmdlet is also supported by the SQL Server Stretch
> Database service on Azure.

Example: Get the import and export status of a SQL database

[image]

So this is normal performance, if you want to get status, you need to specify something like `$importStatus1.Status`.

Comment: But my code "importStatus1.Status " is returning " Running ,Progress =1 %" instead of Inprogress   ie why I have used Match operator in my code